# Can I get the user input text while await parameters in Dailogflow ES fulfillment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, inline-editor

I have an intents named 'testInput' and in this intents, I have two required parameters which is 'params1' and 'params2'.
i.e:

- user: **I wanna test your bot**
- bot: ask required **params1** and **params2**
- user: type **params1** and **params2** value
  In this way, It's OK to get the params1 and params2 value
  but I wanna get all of the user input like **"I wanna test your bot"**,**"params1 value"**, **"params2 value"**

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to get all of the user input. You can use the 'context' provided by the user to answer the question.

Comment: more details please.